# How to avoid API duplication when fetching data with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a route that I may call either from server side rendering, or from client:

```
export const getFooBar = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const res = await fetch(`/foo/bar`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    //do something
  }
  //do something else
}
```

If I call this function from the server:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  getFooBar().then(() => {
    //do something
  })
}
```

I got an error on because it is not an absolute URL. Solution is to create another function with slightly different URI:

```
export const getFooBar = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://myapp/foo/bar`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    //do something
  }
  //do something else
}
```

Or to pass a prefix URL argument in `getFooBar`.

But is there a more generic way to add the absolute URL part if it's coming from server side rendering?

Comment: Is `/foo/bar` an internal API route endpoint or an external API?

Comment: it is an external API. When I'm calling it client side, it is proxied withing `next.config.js`

Comment: Can you share your `next.config.js`?

Comment: sure @juliomalves thanks for taking the time. Here is the gist : https://gist.github.com/audrenbdb/5ff3dceaf5acd0395b1777d301f72f62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy you have set up in `next.config.js` is only relevant for client-side requests. For requests initiated on the server (like inside `getServerSideProps`) you should directly call the external API.

Given the `APP_API` environment variable is not exposed to the browser (it's not prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`), you could use that as a condition to either use the direct API endpoint on the server, or point to the proxy endpoint on the client.

```js
export const getFooBar = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const url = process.env.APP_API ? `http://${process.env.APP_API}/bar` : '/foo/bar'
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
    })
    // Remaining code
}
```

Note that you could also use other conditions to verify if you're in the client or server, for example using `typeof window === 'undefined'`.